# JMeter - how to log the full request for a failed response?

Tags: jmeter

i'm using JMeter command line to stress test our website api. Now, here's a sample result i'm getting back:

```
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using street_advisor.jmx
Starting the test @ Sat Oct 03 15:22:59 PDT 2009 (1254608579848)
Waiting for possible shutdown message on port 4445
summary +     1 in   0.0s =   37.0/s Avg:    27 Min:    27 Max:    27 Err:     1 (100.00%)
<snip a few more lines>
<then i break it>
```

So i'm getting an error.

Currently, all errors are going to a file. When i check that file, it's saying it's a 404. Er.. ok. Is there anyway i can see *exactly* what the request JMeter tried?

here's a snippet of my config file...

```
<ResultCollector guiclass="SimpleDataWriter" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="Error Writer" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">true</boolProp>
          <objProp>
            <name>saveConfig</name>
            <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
              <time>true</time>
              <latency>true</latency>
              <timestamp>false</timestamp>
              <success>true</success>
              <label>true</label>
              <code>true</code>
              <message>true</message>
              <threadName>false</threadName>
              <dataType>true</dataType>
              <encoding>false</encoding>
              <assertions>true</assertions>
              <subresults>true</subresults>
              <responseData>false</responseData>
              <samplerData>false</samplerData>
              <xml>true</xml>
              <fieldNames>false</fieldNames>
              <responseHeaders>true</responseHeaders>
              <requestHeaders>true</requestHeaders>
              <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
              <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>false</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
              <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
              <bytes>true</bytes>
            </value>
          </objProp>
          <stringProp name="filename">./error.jtl</stringProp>
        </ResultCollector>
```

Now, before someone says 'Check the webserver log files', I know I can do this and yep, I've found the 404 .. but i'm hoping to see if it's possible without accessing them .. especially if they are on another server and/or I can't get access to them.
Please help!

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The **[View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree)** component shows a tree of all sample responses, allowing you to view both the request and response for any sample.

When load testing (**Always in NON GUI mode**), fill in "Filename" field and select to only save Responses in Error:

[image: View Results Tree in error]

As you can see above we clicked on Configure to select all fields except CSV ones.

You can also save the entire response to a file using [Save Responses to a file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file):

[image: Save Responses to a file]

Comment: Correct, but i was doing this via the command line .. so I don't have access to the GUI. Bu tI didn't specify that in my question (blush). Also, i couldn't figure out how to do it via the command line, so I ended up doing what you suggested anyways :)

Comment: If you are using the command line you can configure your test to send the data to an output file (jtl) and then process that file with this tool: http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/ to export to PNG or CSV.

Comment: If I read the question correctly, was looking for the logged request not response...?

Comment: @arcseldon good catch! The full request and response are recoreded.

Comment: @rodrigoap - have slightly adjusted your answer, `both the request and response`..

Answer (score 26):

I found this thread searching for a solution to log the response **only** when a sampler fails, so the accepted solution is not good for me. I have occasional sample failures at a very high load involving hundreds of thousands of samples, so a tree listener is completely impractical for me (it will reach several gigabytes in size), so here is what I came up with (which should be good for the OP's scenario as well):

Add a `[JSR223 Assertion][1]` (should come after all the other assertions) and put the below code in it:

```
if (Boolean.valueOf(vars.get("DEBUG"))) {
  for (a: SampleResult.getAssertionResults()) {
    if (a.isError() || a.isFailure()) {
      log.error(Thread.currentThread().getName()+": "+SampleLabel+": Assertion failed for response: " + new String((byte[]) ResponseData));
    }
  }
}
```

This will cause the entire response getting logged to the jmeter log file which is fine in my case, as I know that the responses are really small, but for large responses, more intelligent processing could be done.

Comment: I added the ability to control the log using a UDV called "DEBUG", so it is easier to leave the assertion for the regular workloads, and enable it only when necessary.

Comment: @haridsv Nice Decision! But is it possible to save the requestData which caused failed response?

Comment: @ShurupuS Per the component reference on `BeanShell Assertion`, `RequestHeaders` is available as a variable to the BeanShell code, so it is possible in theory.

Comment: @haridsv can you help me with this?

Comment: In above solution what is "DEBUG" variable. Where and why we need to define "DEBUG" variable

Answer (score 6):

There is a 'Save responses to a file' listener, which can save to file only when error occurs.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I log the full request (request URL + request body) for failed requests.

1. Add a Listener inside the Thread Group

> ```
> try{
>   var message = "";
>   var currentUrl = sampler.getUrl();
>   message +=  ". URL = " +currentUrl;
>   var requestBody = sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue();
>   message += " --data " + sampler.getArguments();
>
>   if(!sampleResult.isSuccessful()){
>       log.error(message);
>   }
>
> }catch(err){
>   //do nothing. this could be a debug sampler. no need to log the error
> }
> ```

For every Sampler inside the Thread Group, the Listener will execute this code after the Sampler.

Comment: what kind of listener is this that you added this code to?

Comment: I used a JSR223 listener. More info about it here: https://www.pushbeta.com/2019/10/18/jmeter-logging-the-full-request-for-non-gui-access/

Answer (score 1):

**2023-04-22**

I added a BeanShell PostProcessor to very top level and have this code:

```
if (!ctx.getPreviousResult().isSuccessful()){
    String httpResponseBody = new String(ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseData());
    log.error(httpResponseBody);
}
```