# When loading JTL file on View results tree listener, it shows NULL request and No response

Tags: jmeter

I ran the Jmeter script in non-GUI mode using the following command:

```
java -jar ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t  C:\XXX\test1.jmx -l C:\YYY\testResult\log${__time(ddMMyy_HHmmss)}.jtl
```

NOTE: the script does not have any Result Listener enabled.

Now when I load the saved JTL file (obtained for non-GUI execution) into View Results tree listener:

- only Sampler results tab is populated;
- Request tab is NULL and Response tab is blank.

How can I see the results in the above tabs too so that I can view how page is load?
Or is there any other alternative to view how page is loaded?

Comment: Hi, I am also facing a similar issue, were you able to resolve it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52641309/why-response-in-jmeter-showing-post-data-request-as-null See above link for solution.

Answer (score 1):

to see the response details in .jtl file, you should make these property changes in your jmeter.properties file which located in your /bin folder.

```
mode=Standard
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true 
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=true
```

and to see the request header and sample post data in request tab, add below properties:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
```

After adding the above properties , you should able to see request and response details in .jtl file. For better analysis , import .jtl file into JMeter UI -->view results tree listener.

Answer (score 0):

You can Save at least the Reques. See [JMeter - how to log the full request for a failed response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515689/jmeter-how-to-log-the-full-request-for-a-failed-response).

But for me the Respons Tab is still empty. Still lokking into the problem.