# Why RESPONSE in jmeter showing Post data request as null

Tags: xml, user-interface

Script is executed in non-gui mode, user.properties file is added with following lines:

```
`jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true `

(tried in jmeter.properties file too)
```

Listener is confirgured to save request and response in xml.
Tree listener is set to 0 to save all results.

When run in non gui mode and when listener is loded in gui mode, its showing NULL for whatever was POST data sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Don't use Listeners in your test, they don't add any value and only consume RAM and create additional disk IO](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing).

1. Add the next lines to *user.properties* file

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
   jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
   jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
   jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
   jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
   jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
   ```
2. [Run your test in command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```
3. Once your test is finished open JMeter GUI
4. Add [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html) listener to Test Plan
5. Using "Browse" button locate `results.jtl` file
6. You should be able to see request and response data for all the requests