# Having test jemeter results in Jenkins build while jmeter forever

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, surefire, jmeter-plugins

I have a jmeter test that is running forever. I have no schedule also. I am running this test using the jenkins job. However when this test is running forever, I would like to see the current status of the test cases. I would like to informed whether test is failing or other states? Is there a way to do to this? 
When we have junit or testng test we can setup a surefire reports which allow us to see the instant status of the test cases during the job. Is there a way to do it in jmeter jobs?

Comment: jmeter is open source. The GUI has real-time result output (IIRC). You may be able to find the stream parser they're using and re-implement it for your needs.

Comment: But i am using the maven plugin. How can i update the source code in that case

Answer (score 0):

Jmeter when run in non-GUI mode allready outputs results in the command line. Standard you can see response times and Error percentage.

If you want to print out more you can open a separate commandline window and tail -f jmeter.log

Also see [JMeter - how to log the full request for a failed response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515689/jmeter-how-to-log-the-full-request-for-a-failed-response)

This contains an example of how you can use a beanshell assertion to log the complete error response message in jmeter.log, which in turn you can see realtime by tailing it.