# Using BeanShell Assertion for saving failed response

Tags: debugging, jmeter, load, load-testing

I'm trying to save the response of failed requests into log but unsuccessfully.
I have HTTP requests which each one has  its own Response assertion, and once in a while through my load test a response doesn't meet the requirements of the Response Assertion, so I want to fail it.
I tried to add this code to the `BeanShell Assertion` following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515689/jmeter-how-to-log-the-full-request-for-a-failed-response):

```
if (Boolean.valueOf(vars.get("DEBUG"))) {
  for (a: SampleResult.getAssertionResults()) {
    if (a.isError() || a.isFailure()) {
      log.error(Thread.currentThread().getName()+": "+SampleLabel+": Assertion failed for response: " + new String((byte[]) ResponseData));
    }
  }
}
```

The Test plan itself looks like this:

[image]

In user defined variables I've added the following:
Name: DEBUG
Value: (none)

I ran this program through the non GUI mode - cmd and on purpose made a response fail (response assertion failed it) but I did not get any error response logged to my log file.
What am I doing wrong?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather let JMeter do this automatically, it is the matter of a couple of properties, to wit:

1. First of all, you need to tell JMeter to store its results in XML format:

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
   ```
2. Second, you can amend the following property values to configure JMeter to store assertion failure message and data into .jtl results file

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=true
   jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results=all
   ```
3. Probably the most useful option: simply save response data for failed samplers:

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true
   ```

The above properties can be either put into *user.properties* file (located in JMeter's "bin" folder, JMeter restart is required to pick the changes up) or you can pass them via `-J` command line argument like:

```
jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true ....
```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on working with JMeter Properties to tune various aspects of JMeter configuration

Comment: Thanks, how can I save the request also and not only the response?

Answer (score 2):

First of all if your goal is to just save failed responses, together with assertion results, you don't need any custom code. You can add [Simple Data Writer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) configured like this:

[image]

Option 2: If you want to write responses into the log file, then you need custom script. But in that case I'd suggest using [BeanShell Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Listener) (unlike assertions and other objects, there's only 1 instance of listener for all threads, so it's more economical, and less chance to create a bottleneck at log writing).

Also according to your script, the value of `DEBUG` must be `true`, but as you mentioned, you did not set it to `true` (empty string will be resolved to `false` by Java's `valueOf`). So change it to

```
Name: DEBUG 
Value: true
```

Here's how such BeanShell Listener's script looks:

```
if (Boolean.valueOf(vars.get("DEBUG"))) {
  for (a: sampleResult.getAssertionResults()) {
    if (a.isError() || a.isFailure()) {
      log.error(sampleResult.getThreadName() + ": " 
                + sampleResult.getSampleLabel() + ": Assertion failed for response: " 
                + sampleResult.getResponseDataAsString());
    }
  }
}
```

Option 3 is to stay with your original solution, then you need to fix the variable assignment (as I mentioned before).