# JMeter Beanshell sampler that runs when HTTP Request Sampler fails

Tags: java, jmeter

I need a Beanshell sampler that runs only when a specific HTTP Request Sampler fails. I want this so I can write certain variables to the terminal console when this failure occurs during test execution.

I know I can save the http response to a file upon failures [using built in jmeter component Save Responses to File] and include variables in the name of the file saved, but this is too heavyweight for what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not set up a beanshell sampler with an if condition that tests the result's HTTP status? The script would look something like this:

```
if (!ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseCode().equals("200")) {
    log.info("Your log message here.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out.  Beanshell to save response to log on failure. 
 Perhaps you can modify this concept to write variables to terminal instead of responses to file https://stackoverflow.com/a/13931040/7003774

Comment: This is a good answer but it didn't print to console  when the status code was a failure. Very close though so I upvoted.

Comment: have you tried the print statement with your variables?  See 1 and 2 here:
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-beanshell-beginners-no-java-knowledge-required

Comment: Yes after adding the print statement, this did not work when status code was unsuccessful.